# regex for list comparing?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to filter out some objects based on an attribute property in C#.  I've decided to do this based on comparing two comma delimited lists such that:

- "a,b,c"  ~ "a,b,c", "a,c,b", "c,a,b", etc..
- "a,b,*"  ~ "a,b,c", "a,d,b", "g,a,b", "a,b", etc..
- "a,b,c" !~ "a,c,d", "a,c", "a", etc..

I figure you should be able to do this with a simple regex match expression but I can't figure it out as yet.

Anyone know how to do this?  In the mean time going to brute force it with code.

Thanks in advance

--EDIT

by ~ I mean equivalent, sorry for confusion.

also "a,b,c" could also be "abra,barby,candybar".  Its not single characters but a list of values.

Comment: I'd rather write normal code for this... I know it is totally possible to force regex solution, but I'd rather not go there.

Comment: what is `~`. am not able to understand what do u want to do...

Comment: @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It: Permutation, probably.

Comment: ~ means soft equivalency,  I don't like to use = when it isn't really equal

Comment: Should `a,b,c,a` match your first example?

Comment: @danatcofo: Can you formally define your operator? This is your own "invention", so you should know what it means better than any of us can guess.

Comment: "I've decided to do this based on comparing two comma delimited lists" - This is where you're going wrong.  Converting anything to a string just makes it harder to work with.

Comment: @nhahtdh  ~ is the closest character I have on the keyboard to the mathematical equivalency operator ≅  which I have to find via charmap

Comment: @Bobson I'm not converting anything to a string, it starts as a string so that the attributes can be used to filter which objects I find via reflection. Its loose binding to for the inner workings of an distributed logic engine.

Comment: @danatcofo - In that case, parsing it as a string instead of converting it into something else is where you're going wrong.

Comment: @Bobson engine needs to be able to be extended easily by 3rd parties. string comparison allows the integration between the various peeps.  The strings are in essense tags to indicate this object is meant to handle a specific message based on the message property that self describes itself.  The message format is static so that they can be passed around and consumed in a distributed network

Comment: @danatcofo - Yeah, strings make a lot of sense for that case.  It's trying to drive logic based on them **directly** which I object to.  Parsing them into something else makes them much easier to work with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a regular expression, but it's much simpler than any one could possibly be.

```
var attributes = input.Split(",");
var testCase = test.Split(",");

return attributes.All(x => testCase.Contains(x)) && testCase.All(x => attributes.Contains(x);
```

If you find a *, leave off one half of the `&&` expression.

Comment: yah, that is less work to do.  mine turned into an '... && (attributes.Any(x => x == "*") || textCase.All(x => attributes.Contains(x)))'

Answer (score 2):

If you *want* a regex, here's [my take on this](http://rubular.com/r/y1aFK2Vv5T):

```
^                       # match start of string
 (?=.*a(?:,|$))         # assert it matches a followed by a comma or end-of-str
 (?=.*b(?:,|$))         # assert it matches b followed by a comma or end-of-str
 (?=.*c(?:,|$))         # assert it matches c followed by a comma or end-of-str
 (?:(?:a|b|c)(?:,|$))*  # match a, b or c followed by a comma or end-of-str
$                       # match end of string
```

In case you find a `.*`, you keep the assertions but change the last part of the regex to allow it to match anything. [Second example](http://rubular.com/r/HpCE1MI1xN):

```
^                       # match start of string
 (?=.*a(?:,|$))         # assert it matches a followed by a comma or end-of-str
 (?=.*b(?:,|$))         # assert it matches b followed by a comma or end-of-str
 (?:[^,]*(,|$))*        # match anything followed by a comma or end-of-str
$                       # match end of string
```

---

Of course you'll still need to parse the string to generate the regex, and at this point I frankly would prefer to just use conventional code (it would probably be faster too), eg (pseudo code):

```
setRequired  = Set(csvRequired.Split(','))
setActual    = Set(input.Split(','))

if (setActual.Equals(setRequired)))
{
    // passed
}
```

If you find the asterisk, just remove it from `setRequired` and use `.Contains` instead of `Equals`

Comment: [alternate first](http://rubular.com/r/ieLdBFMxx9)  result of testing the first scenario with words versus letters.  worked like a charm!

Comment: I'm thinking its probably still less computation to brute force the comparison...  the regex could get expensive.

Comment: @danatcofo The regex doesn't do any magic, it still has to go and find all those strings. More likely than not, conventional code will be faster. I wrote the regex more to to see if I could.

Comment: @NullUserException: The solution for 1 is correct but not really extensible if the original list on LHS of ~ is bba, ba, a - where your regex will looks like: `^(?=.*bba(?:,|$))(?=.*ba(?:,|$))(?=.*a(?:,|$))(?:(?:bba|ba|a)(?:,|$))*$` which will match `bba,bba,bba`. The second one **in the current state** accepts `ab,ba`.

Answer (score -2):

Try 
`((a|b|c)(,|))+`

where a, b and c are every option in the list. [Here's](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%28%28a%7Cb%7Cc%29%28,%7C%29%29%2b&input=a,c,d%0A%0Aa,c,b%0A%0Ac,b,a%0A%0Aa,x,b%0A) the perma link to my quick tests in regexpal. If you look at the last test "a,x,b" the regex matches two separate parts but I think it will still work in C# using Regex.Match()

Comment: I can get aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa to match your regex.